# mediaType text/csv is not supported by ObjectSerializer.parse (React/NestJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, nestjs, openapi

We are using OpenAPI, React, Node/Nest.js. All in Typescript.

I've created an endpoint which gets a `csv` file from a remote API and streams it directly to our React client with Nest's built in `StreamableFile`

```
return new StreamableFile(file);
```

It works great with Postman, but in React i'm getting this error in console:

> The mediaType text/csv is not supported by ObjectSerializer.parse

What am I doing wrong?